# Using Map in Open Binary

Tags: python-3.x

trying to use map() in my script which reads files and converts them into binary form.

Cant get the below to work, any help?

```
def binary_file_reader(file_data):
    with open(file_data, 'rb') as binary_file_data:
        binary_file_data = binary_file_data.read()
        print(binary_file_data)
        binary_data = binascii.hexlify(binary_file_data)
        binary_data = binary_data.decode("utf-8")
    return binary_data
```

Then the main which calls the above

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    device_directory = os.getcwd()

    for r, d, f in os.walk(device_directory):
        for file in f:
            file_data = os.path.join(r, file)
            all_file_names.append(file_data)

    try:
        binary_data = map(binary_file_reader, all_file_names)
        print(binary_data)
       
    except IOError:
        print("cannot read")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `map` applies `binary_file_reader` to every element inside `file_data`, it doesn't do what you think it is.

In your case, `file_data` is your actual file path as a `str`, e.g., `/tmp/a.txt`. If you use `map` on a `str`, it is applied on every letter, so what you do will be expanded to

```
binary_file_reader('/')
binary_file_reader('t')
binary_file_reader('m')
binary_file_reader('p')
binary_file_reader('/')
binary_file_reader('a')
binary_file_reader('.')
binary_file_reader('t')
binary_file_reader('x')
binary_file_reader('t')
```

`binary_file_reader(file_data)` should produce the desired result.

Comment: many thanks, yep had that method working but tried applying it with map to use multi-threading. I think ill need to add it to a list first (os.walk) then run the list through the binary ready with map

Comment: @RajB_007 Hmm... I think `multiprocessing.Pool.map(binary_file_reader, f)` may help. You could try it. `map(func, var)` is equivalent to `for v in var: func(v)`. Having that in mind will help you understand `map` better.

Comment: I can have a look into multiprocessing, but using map with the function and the list doesn't work. Map takes the iterative as a string I believe, and for some reason my function isn't firing. Not even hitting any break points within the function. Any ideas here?

Comment: So weird. Have you tested the very first `Pool` example on [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)? You need to pass a list of file names to `Pool.map` like `pool.map(func, ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt'])`.